# In vue3, why my parent event handler arguments isn't typed with his child's defineEmits definition?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm trying to have my parent event handler correctly typed from his child definition but I can't figure out why I still get `any` as event type.

Code example

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
// Child component
type EventPayload = {
  foo: boolean
}
const emits = defineEmits<{
  'my-event': [EventPayload]
}>()

const onClick = () => {
  emits('my-event', { foo: true})
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="onClick" />
</template>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
// Parent component
const onMyEvent = ({ foo }) => { // type error Binding element 'foo' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  console.log(foo)
}
</script>

<template>
  <child @my-event="onMyEvent" />
<template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is how Vue [works](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-event-handlers).

> Without type annotation, the event argument will implicitly have a type of any

Just as it says in the documents I would suggest adding the type to the argument of the event handler function.

```
const onMyEvent = ({ foo }: EventPayload) => {
  console.log(foo)
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure, thanks for the extra infos